# Manga about a boy who died and got reincarnated with OP stats

Tags: story-identification, manga

Does anyone know what this manga is? It's about a boy who died because of a specific God but got reincarnated by a different God, and because of the mistake of the god who reincarnated him, his OP stats were hidden so his noble family (not royal) abandoned him thinking he was useless. But he only recalls his memories after he is abandoned and his is already around 5(i think).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. However, there are literally dozens of manga with a reincarnated, OP MC, who's abandoned because everyone thinks they're weak. We really need some more info about the plot/setting/characters to have a realistic shot at identifying this. You might want to take a look at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details that come to mind.

Comment: I get that people who are into manga will probably understand this, but what on earth are "OP stats"?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - OP stats = Over-Powered [in comparison to normal individuals in their class] Statistics

Comment: OP stats=over powered stats

Comment: ok thanks 4 advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely *[Shoki Skill ga Benri Sugite Isekai Seikatsu ga Tanoshi Sugiru!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shoki-skill-ga-benri-sugite-isekai-seikatsu-ga-tanoshi-sugiru) (The Initial Skill Is Too Convenient and Life in the Otherworld Is Too Fun!)*.

> High-schooler Shinomiya Raku was **reincarnated due to a wicked god toying with his fate**, which ended in his untimely death in the previous world. Reborn as Larucu, a silver-haired boy, he possesses **super convenient skills he received as an apology for his death**, and is now filled with great hope to lead a fulfilling, smooth-sailing second life. However, he was soon struck by a series of catastrophic events, starting by **getting expelled from his family** and then collapsing down the road.

Synopsis covers much of it. One god toys with his fate and causes various disasters in our world, eventually killing him. A different god makes up for this by reincarnating him in another world and offering various skills.

The evil god continues messing with him and seals his memory until after he's 10, with the complication that this made it look like he had no skills at all.

[image: Letter of apology from god, explaining why he had no memory until now]

Having no skills resulting in him being expelled from his noble family. It's not stated what rank his family was; it's just shown as a generally well-off family.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!! I have been looking for this manga for so long!

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *"[Am I Actually the Strongest?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/am-i-actually-the-strongest)"*?

> To be reincarnated into another world with the promise of a “cheat” power is one thing… but to be reborn as a baby, and then left for dead after your royal parents think you’re powerless?? That’s another thing entirely! Now the newly-born Reinhart—or Hart to his new friends—must find his way through a dangerous world…but luckily he’s got magic that’s quite literally off the charts!
>
> [image]

Comment: thanks but i don't think this is it